# How to initialise boolean variables in react?

Tags: reactjs

i have a variable named data which is a array of objects as below,

```
  data = [
          { attributes: [],
            info: '',
            meshes: [],
          }
          {attributes: [],
           info: '',
           meshes: [],
           }
           .....so on.... 
          ]
```

When the info is defined will display message info available..if info `undefined` will display message info unavailable.

So i do it like below within render function of the component

```
export default class DataInfo extends React.Purecomponent {
    state = {
        data: null,
    };

    componentdidMount() {
        load_data();
    }
    load_data = () => {
        /*send a request to server for fetching data and 
        set data state */
    }

    render = () => {
        return (
            {this.loading &&
                <div className="spinner"/>}
            {!this.data || (this.data && this.data.every((data.info) => 
            !data.info)) && 
                <div>No info available</div>}
            {this.data && this.data.some((data.info) => data.info) &&
                <div>info available</div>}
         );
     }
}
```

Now withing the conditionals rather than using the below statements,

```
this.data.every((data.info) => !data.info)
this.data.some((data.info) => data.info)
```

I want to have them defined as some explanatory variables...like `has_some_info` and `has_no_info`.

So to achieve it, within render function i tried using something like below,

```
const has_some_info = this.data ? this.data.some((data.info) => 
data.info): 'false';
const has_no_info = this.data ? this.data.every((data.info) => 
!data.info): 'false';
```

But this is not correct. it doesnt work fine..i don't want to initialise it to intialise variables to false....

Could someone help me to defined these variables....thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first place, you should realize that `every` and `some` are the opposites and you don't have to calculate them both:

```
const infoAvailable = (this.state.data || []).some(data => data.info);
const noInfoAvailable = !infoAvailable;
```

In other words:

```
render() {
   if (this.state.loading) {
       return <div className="spinner"/>;
   }

   const infoAvailable = (this.state.data || []).some(data => data.info);

   return infoAvailable
      ? <div>Info available</div>
      : <div>No info available</div>;
}
```

(also note I have used `this.state.data` to access data).

Answer (score 0):

```
export default class DataInfo extends React.Purecomponent {
state = {
    data: null,
};

componentdidMount() {
    load_data();
}
load_data = () => {
    /*send a request to server for fetching data and 
    set data state */
}

render() {
 const {loading, data = []} = this.state;
    return (
        {loading &&
            <div className="spinner"/>}
        {data.map(ele => ele.info 
                ? <div>info available - {ele.info} </div>
                : <div>No info available</div>
        }
     );
 }
}
```

If you need self explanatory variables for info you could use !!ele.info which gives whether data is present or not.